# Can ICANN deny Internet service to people?

Tags: dns, ip, internet

I had an argument with a co-worker yesterday about the recent transfer of the administration of ICANN.

My co-worker said that, since ICANN has control over the assignment of (a) IP addresses and (b) HTTP domain names, that means ICANN can effectively (a)  deny Internet service to ISPs by not giving them any IP addresses to use, and (b)  deny [convenient] access to certain websites by not giving them a domain to use. Hence, the news headlines like "The U.S. has given up control of the Internet" are accurate, and we might expect in the future ICANN denying Internet service to copyright infringers, political dissidents, or warring nations.

I was under the impression that (a) ICANN selectively refusing to assign IP addresses would not result in ISPs unable to provide Internet service, since those ISPs could just pick random IP addresses to give out [however, that would be immensely annoying to deal with, since the uniqueness of IP addresses is relied upon for many services and programs as of right now]; and (b) people could work around not being granted domain names to use by distributing the IP address for their websites [although again, that would be immensely annoying to deal with]. Hence, people rely on ICANN because it makes the Internet more convenient, but it would be a wild exaggeration to say they "control the Internet", and it's really in nobody's interests at all to attempt to censor anybody through ICANN.

Who is right?

Comment: This doesn't seem at all like an Information Security question, but AFAIK ICANN doesn't really have any real "power" on its own. They're just a standards body. They make recommendations, but it's up to ISPs and browser/OS vendors to implement those recommendations, and there's technically nothing _forcing_ them to listen to ICANN if they don't want to.

Answer (score 1):

ICANN only has authority to assign blocks of IP addresses to regional nics -- e.g. ARIN, APNIC, RIPE.  From there, the regional NIC (in the U.S. ARIN) then decides how to allocate the IP address to various entities like ISPs and corporations.  So, ICANN is at a much higher level than individual IP address assignment and it's very unlikely they'd ever become involved in this level of detail -- this is for regional NICs to handle.

As far as domain names go, ICANN has the authority to accredit registrars, but does not actually supervise them on the level of granting/revoking domain names.  Sure, if a registrar went against their policies they could theoretically revoke that accreditation -- but that would be unlikely since it would probably cause issues for all the other domains registered through that registrar.

I think you and your co-worker might misunderstand about "control of the internet" -- that's largely due to US control of the root DNS servers of the internet.  Previously, Jon Postel (the closest thing to a saint in internet history); an inventor of DNS, tried to move control of DNS from a US corporation to IANA (now part of ICANN) -- but was met with swift rebuke and clawback from the Clinton administration. Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jon_Postel

As it turns out, control of the root DNS servers has been interpreted by the press as "control of the internet," but other nations such as China and Russia laready have contingency plans to migrate to their own DNS system if relations degrade with the US.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I would say that *neither* of you have it right.

First off, there is no such thing as a "HTTP domain name". A domain name is an entity that exists in the [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) system, plain and simple. The world wide web, which uses the HTTP protocol as its primary transmission protocol, is one of many Internet applications that relies on domain names for ease of use as well as practical issues (such as using name-based virtual hosting).

The recent transfer of control to ICANN was of the DNS root zone. That's the part of DNS that tells computers where to go to get answers about which names exist under the `com`, `sg`, `info`, `fr`, `au`, `ua` and so on top-level domains. As a consequence, ICANN could, in principle, just like the US government previously could on its own accord, remove a top-level domain such as `com` from the public DNS root. They could *in theory* point a given second-level domain name (such as `example.com`) to something other than what was intended, but in practice it almost certainly wouldn't work out except for a tiny sliver of the Internet's users a small percentage of the time. This is the same power that the US government previously wielded; the difference now is that the power is held by a body not controlled by any single entity.

End users don't register top-level domains; they register second-level domains, such as `example.com` or `funnycatvideos.example` (yes, that's a [valid example domain name](https://michael.kjorling.se/computers/internet-reservations/examples-and-documentation)). For this, they deal with whoever control of the relevant top-level domain has been delegated to, or an authorized reseller thereof.

ICANN also manages top-level assignment of IP addresses. ICANN delegates IP ranges to a small number of regional registries, including ARIN (services mainly North America), RIPE (services mainly Europe), LACNIC (services mainly Latin America), AFRINIC (services mainly Africa) and so on. Notice that these regions are very large, and the assignments are rarely smaller than perhaps an IPv4 /10 or so. (That's literally millions of IP addresses apiece.) These registries in turn may sub-delegate IP address assignment for various areas, or they may assign address blocks directly to ISPs within their operating area.

An ISP doesn't deal with ICANN directly for obtaining IP addresses, *possibly unless* it is right among the largest ISPs in the world. Rather, it deals with its regional registry, requesting blocks that can commonly be on the order of /16 to /20 (IPv4) (thousands to tens of thousands of addresses) in size and which are assigned out of the pools allocated to the regional registry. The ISP then, in turn, subnets and sublets out of this assignment both for their own internal use as well as for use by their customers.

**While the ICANN *could* in theory block a web site or an ISP that is considered inconvenient to someone, doing so would be somewhat akin to demolishing a whole town because one house needs a new door knob: It would probably mean that the house gets a new door knob, but it would be a totally disproportionate response. Its tools are simply far too coarse-grained for that to be realistic. Just like they were while they were under the control of the single country of the United States of America.**

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, you should understand that IP addresses are delegated at every level.  No one can decide to use a certain IP on their own as it simply will not work.

No one can predict the future and be 1000% sure that there will never be any bad management at ICANN, but their operations are exclusively based on allowing the different service providers and customers access to the Internet.  They do not worry about what you put on your website.

As for domain names, those are delegated too and managed by the respective TLDs which already have their own terms of use which must be respected.

All in all, I doubt there will be any change at all to the way ICANN operates.  In my opinion, this was a political move from the US government to show transparency in a time where the world's population is learning how they've repeatedly gotten involved and spied on people injustifiedly.